# Getting list of files from azure explorer directory takes too much time

Tags: python, azure, bigdata

I have a directory in azure datalake storage, the folder has more than 600k files. I am using the following code to get the list of files form that directory ref [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-datalake-store/azure.datalake.store.core.azuredlfilesystem?view=azure-python):

```
az.azure_client = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token=token, store_name=self.store_name)
dirs = az.azure_client.listdir(azure_root_dir)
```

This takes ~130 seconds, and I'd like to find faster way to get a subset of these files (ex: last created 100 files).

I've explored also:

```
az.azure_client.ls(azure_root_dir)
az.azure_client.glob(azure_root_dir+ '*' + str(now.year) + '*' + str(now.month) + '*')
```

This doesn't give faster performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use the following code in order to get the files between specified date time range,

```
filter to get file list in a folder, which file modification time between[start_date,end_date]
    """
    @staticmethod
    def get_files_list(path_to_folder,start_date=None,end_date=None):
        file_list = []
        if start_date and end_date:
            if isinstance(start_date,date) and isinstance(end_date,date):
                folder_file_list = os.listdir(path_to_folder)
                for f in folder_file_list:
                    #print os.path.getmtime(f)
                    file_mtime = date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(f))
                    if start_date <= file_mtime <= end_date:
                        file_list.append(os.path.join(path_to_folder,f))
            else:
                print 'start or end datetime format error!'
        else:
            folder_file_list = os.listdir(path_to_folder)
            for f in folder_file_list:
                file_list.append(os.path.join(path_to_folder,f))
        return file_list
```

You can find the whole extension from [`here`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DaiHanpeng/CentralDB/b97a35aba30ed20d9dadbd56a160b9f68a57b0f6/FilesFilter/FilesFilter.py)

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan thanks for the reply. not sure that os.listdir() works on Azure directory...